# Adobe Flash successfully installed for Chromium, but still not usable

Tags: flash, chromium

I tried to install the Flash Player on Chromium by typing

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Everything is installed and I get the message

```
Using PPAPI flash.
```

once starting Chromium. However, Flash does not seem to be available.

```
chrome://components
```

does not show any entry for Flash. Websites are still asking to installl flash. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash will not appear under `chrome://components`. Instead you need to look at `chrome://settings/content/flash` to see if it is enabled. Some sites may behave weird when `Ask first` is the behavior, and may need to explicitly allow those sites to use flash without asking.